# Java Syntax that executes Block statements through conditional expressions

Tags: java, syntax, conditional-statements, block

Are there any Java Syntax that executes Block statements through conditional expressions other than:

```
if
while
do/while
switch
for
foreach
try/catch
```

?

Comment: That doesn't execute a block statement.  Or any statement.

Comment: @StephenC Yeah, but to be honest, I don't even know what that means, *"Java Syntax that executes Block statements"*. Does `if` "execute" a block statement? In that sense, `assert` seemed to be the only keyword not in the list that controls the flow of execution based on the evaluation of a conditional expression.

Comment: I wasn't sure what the OP meant either, but I wasn't going to inquire ...

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen It seems perfectly clear to me. `if` and friends control a statement, and a statement can be a block. `assert` does not control a statement.

Comment: @OP `foreach`, `switch`, and `try/catch` don't have a conditional expression. If you omit that requirement you've left out `else`.